# Shimano disc brake hose compatibility

Tags: disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake

I have a bike with Shimano XT disc brakes, model BR M775, which have too short brake lines for my new stem. 
So I want to replace them with longer brake lines. But when I go shopping for brake hose, there are many different ones. Shimano LX, XT, XTR, Saint etc. 
I realize I have to get plain hose without banjo bolts, but can I use any of the Shimano ones?
And are there any 3rd party ones worth considering?

Comment: Doesn't shimano has like two basic hoses, the older BH-59 (wide bore) and newer BH-90 (narrow bore)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: SI for M775 brakes]

You need any BH59 hose with the right ends. The commonly seen current model kit would be BH59-JK-SS, comes in black or white and 1700mm or 2000mm.