# Shimano hydraulic hose - BH90-SB compatible with BH90-J/JK

Tags: disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake

My problem, I have a complete M7000 (MTB) brake set that uses SM-BH90-SB hose, and now I want to connect a 105er BR-R7070 brake caliper that needs SM-BH90-JK-SSR or SM-BH90-J-SSR hose.

Are the two hoses compatible? I am aware that BH90-SB uses a banjo connector, obviously that need to go. Can I just cut it off, fix the pin and olive and connect it to the R7070? Anybody here done that?

PS: can pins/olives be reused (just in case I can get them out)?

Answer (score 3):

> Are the two hoses compatible?

Judging from [related](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/51648/9215) [questions](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/47385/9215) and my experience, Shimano hoses are interchangeable (same for calipers) and most people won't notice the difference without dedicated comparison procedure.

> I am aware that BH90-SB uses a banjo connector, obviously that need to
>   go. Can I just cut it off, fix the pin and olive and connect it to the
>   R7070?

Yes, that will be enough. You should be able to use [standard Shimano caliper inline furniture](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-RADBR01-03-ENG.pdf)(page 13).

Just in case, R7000/R8000/R9100 series hydro shifter require special flanged bolt.